# Выражение должно иметь константное значение

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Писал программу на CodeBlocks, всё работает исправно, но при переходе на Visual Studio начал выдавать ошибку "выражение должно иметь константное значение. Подскажите, как исправить или в чём суть ошибки, ибо при обозначение константой возникает другая ошибка " выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левостороним значением"

```
#include           <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
struct abonents
{
char family[20];
char name[20];
char phonenum[12];
};

FILE *f;
const char* DOC = "abonents phone";
int main() {
system("chcp 1251 > nul");
int T = 15, K = 15, i;
    const int n;
char menu;

do {
    f = fopen("DOC.dat", "rb");
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    int fn = ftell(f) / sizeof(abonents);
    fclose(f);

    cout << "1 - Просмотр всего справочника" << endl;
    cout << "2 - Добавление новой записи" << endl;
    cout << "3 - Поиск абонента по имени и фамилии и вывод рапорта в текстовый файл" << endl;
    cout << "4 - Очистка \ создание файла" << endl;
    cout << "5 - Удаление записи" << endl;
    cout << "6 - Редактирование записи" << endl;
    cout << "7 - Вывод справочника в текстовый файл" << endl;
    cout << "8 - Выход" << endl;

    cin >> menu;

    switch (menu) {


    case '1': {
        system("cls");

        f = fopen("DOC.dat", "rb");
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
        n = ftell(f) / sizeof(abonents);
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
        abonents t[n];
        fread(&t, sizeof(abonents), n, f);
        fclose(f);

        cout << "Абонент: " << n << '\n' << endl;
        cout << "|Фамилия:              |Имя:                  | Телефон:        |" << endl;
        cout << "|                      |                      |                 |" << endl;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cout << setiosflags(ios::left);;
            cout << "| ";
            cout << setw(20) << t[i].family << " | ";
            cout << setw(20) << t[i].name << " | ";
            cout << setw(15) << t[i].phonenum << " |" << endl;
        }
        cout << "|                                                               |" << endl;
        _getch();
        system("cls");
        break;
        break;
    }

    case '2': {
        system("cls");

        abonents t;
        cout << "Фамилия: "; cin >> t.family;
        cout << "Имя: "; cin >> t.name;
        cout << "Телефон: "; cin >> t.phonenum;
        cout << '\n';


        f = fopen("DOC.dat", "ab");
        fwrite(&t, sizeof(abonents), 1, f);
        fclose(f);
        break;
    }

    case '3': {
        system("cls");

        char name[20]; char family[20];
        cout << "Введите Фамилию: "; cin >> family;
        cout << "Введите Имя: "; cin >> name;

        f = fopen("DOC.dat", "rb");
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
        fn = ftell(f) / sizeof(abonents);
        fclose(f);
        f = fopen("DOC.dat", "r");
        abonents t[n];
        fread(&t, sizeof(abonents), n, f);
        fclose(f);

        f = fopen("SearchAbonents.txt", "wt");
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (strcmp(t[i].family, family) == 0 && strcmp(t[i].name, name) == 0)
            {
                fprintf(f, "Телефон абонента ");
                fprintf(f, family);
                fprintf(f, " ");
                fprintf(f, name);
                fprintf(f, " -> ");
                fprintf(f, t[i].phonenum);
            }
        fclose(f);
        cout << '\n' << "Все номера абонента " << family << name << " введены в файл SearchAbonents.txt." << endl;
        system("notepad.exe SearchAbonents.txt");
        cout << endl;
        break;
    }

    case '4': {
        int del;

        while (true)
        {
            system("cls");
            cout << "Вы уверены, что хотите удалить запись?" << endl;
            cout << " 1 – Да" << endl;
            cout << " 0 – Нет" << endl;
            cin >> del;
            cout << endl;
            if (del == 1)
            {
                f = fopen("DOC.dat", "wb");
                fclose(f);
                cout << "Запись удалена!\n" << endl;
                break;
            }

            if (del == 0)
            {
                cout << "Удаление отменено.\n" << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
        break;
    }

    case '5': {
        system("cls");
        char name[20]; char family[20];
        cout << "Введите фамилию: "; cin >> family;
        cout << "Введите имя: "; cin >> name;

        f = fopen("DOC.dat", "rb");
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
        fn = ftell(f) / sizeof(abonents);
        fclose(f);
        f = fopen("DOC.dat", "r");
        abonents t[n];
        fread(&t, sizeof(abonents), n, f);
        fclose(f);

        f = fopen("DOC.dat", "wb");
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (strcmp(t[i].name, name) != 0 && strcmp(t[i].family, family) != 0)
                fwrite(&t[i], sizeof(abonents), 1, f);
            else
                cout << endl << "Номер телефона удалён: " << t[i].phonenum << endl;
        fclose(f);

        cout << endl;
        break;

    }

    case '6': {
        system("cls");

        f = fopen("DOC.dat", "rb");
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
        fn = ftell(f) / sizeof(abonents);
        fclose(f);
        f = fopen("DOC.dat", "r");
        abonents t[n];
        fread(&t, sizeof(abonents), n, f);
        fclose(f);

        char name[20]; char family[20];
        cout << "Введите абонента, запись которого нужно изменить: " << '\n' << endl;
        cout << "Фамилия :"; cin >> family;
        cout << "Имя: "; cin >> name;

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (strcmp(t[i].name, name) == 0 && strcmp(t[i].family, family) == 0)
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    system("cls");
                    cout << "Запись номера " << i + 1 << endl;
                    cout << "Фамилия: " << t[i].family << endl;
                    cout << "Имя: " << t[i].name << endl;
                    cout << "Телефон: " << t[i].phonenum << endl << endl;
                    cout << "Редактировать запись?\n" << endl;
                    cout << " 1 – Да" << endl;
                    cout << " 0 – Нет" << endl;
                    int edit;
                    cin >> edit; cout << endl;
                    if (edit == 0) break;
                    if (edit == 1)
                    {
                        system("cls");
                        cout << "Редактировать запись под номером " << i + 1 << endl << endl;
                        cout << "Измените фамилию: " << endl << "  " << t[i].family << " -> "; cin >> t[i].family;
                        cout << "Измените имя: " << endl << "  " << t[i].name << " -> "; cin >> t[i].name;
                        cout << "Измените телефон: " << endl << "  " << t[i].phonenum << " -> "; cin >> t[i].phonenum;
                        cout << endl;
                        f = fopen("DOC.dat", "wb");
                        fwrite(&t, sizeof(abonents), n, f);
                        fclose(f);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        break;
    }
    case '7': {
        system("cls");

        f = fopen("DOC.dat", "rb");
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
        fn = ftell(f) / sizeof(abonents);
        fclose(f);
        f = fopen("DOC.dat", "rb");
        abonents t[n];
        fread(&t, sizeof(abonents), n, f);
        fclose(f);

        f = fopen("abonents.txt", "wt");
        fprintf(f, "Фамилия:            |Имя:             | Телефон:\n");
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 19 - strlen(t[i].family); j++) fprintf(f, " ");
            fprintf(f, t[i].family);
            fprintf(f, " | ");
            for (int j = 0; j < 15 - strlen(t[i].name); j++) fprintf(f, " ");
            fprintf(f, t[i].name);
            fprintf(f, " | ");
            for (int j = 0; j < 11 - strlen(t[i].phonenum); j++) fprintf(f, " ");
            fprintf(f, t[i].phonenum);
            fprintf(f, "\n");
        }
        fclose(f);
        while (true)
        {
            int open;
            cout << "Открыть файл" << endl;
            cout << " 1 – Да" << endl;
            cout << " 0 – Нет" << endl;
            cout << "Команда: "; cin >> open;
            cout << endl;
            system("cls");
            if (open == 0) break;
            if (open == 1)
            {
                system("notepad.exe abonents.txt");
                break;
            }
        }
        system("pause");
        break;
    }
    case '8': {

        return 0;
        break;
    }
    }
} while (menu != '8');
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Уберите лишний код, оставив только кусок с ошибкой и приведите саму ошибку (как есть)

Comment: А что по Вашему должно происходить при таком объявлении `const int n;` и такой команде ниже `n = ftell(f) / sizeof(abonents);`? Неужели CodeBlocks + gcc на это совсем не ругались?

Comment: Почему в вопросе не указаны конкретные строки кода, в которых происходят ошибки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В языке С++ не допускается объявление массивов с размером, который не является константным выражением. Поэтому ваше

```
abonents t[n];
```

заведомо не верно и никаким добавлением куда-либо `const` исправить вы это не сможете. Если вы хотите, чтобы размер вашего массива зависел от размера файла - создавайте свой массив через `new []` или, лучше, используйте `std::vector`.

Answer (score 5):

Смотрите - у вас есть

```
const int n;
```

Но чему равно это `n`? Если это константа? Вы потом пишете

```
n = ftell(f) / sizeof(abonents);
```

но константу изменять нельзя...

После этого вы объявляете

```
abonents t[n];
```

Но С++ не разрешает объявлять массивы не известного во время компиляции размера.

Если последнее - с массивом - GCC пропускает как расширение, то как вы ухитрялись присваивать значение константе - непонятно.

Comment: В вопросе я писал, что при объявлении константы, выдаёт ошибку и при объявлени, через int, выдаёт ошибку «выражение должно иметь константное значение»

Comment: А я о чем вам написал? Первая ошибка - объявление константы без инициализатора, вторая - что *по сути* `n` у вас не константа, во время компиляции ее значение неизвестно. Что не так?